# Help for Creating Web map application

Tags: wms, web-mapping

I would like to create a web application with map and I am wondering which platform to use. I don't have enough budgets to build my own GIS server infrastructure. As a base map I am going to use available WMS, and on top of it there will be points, lines and polygons. The problem is that I want to have full control over my GDB and to use time enabled data. Can you help me with some ideas?

Comment: Hi, welcome to GIS stackexchange.  To get the best sort of answers, you'll need to add a little more detail to your question.  Stuff like.. what are you going to be using this application for?

Comment: What do you mean by 'full control over my GDB'? Does your application need to sync/update data or is it a one time thing? Data won't remain in GDB, it will be converted to a format for delivering to the web. A most basic solution would be CartoDB, they have an easy time enabling solution called Torque.  But like Guy said, it all kind of depends on the details of your application.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your quick replies. I am planning to create a web application for a small region with information about attractions, hotels, etc. and main activities in the region. And I would like to visualize them on a web map. When I said to have a full control over GDB, I mean that I need to be able to make DB edits including multiple features edits.

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of tools for making web map applications but each is suited to a particular use case. The real question is what skills you have and what tools your users require.

If you don't want to write/maintain any code and require a rich array of tools out of the box then you should checkout [MangoMap](https://mangomap.com). Here's an example of the type of maps that can be quickly produced without writing a lick of code:

https://mangomap.com/maps/28077/Lower%20Manhattan%20Commercial%20Space%20Analysis

https://mangomap.com/maps/25821/Bristol%20Property%20Finder#

Mango also has data editing tools so you can keep your data up to date from within the app or easily replace existing data by doing a simple upload.

Answer (score 1):

I'd take a [look at CartoDB](http://cartodb.com/), especially for the time enabled stuff. It's also possible (with a paid subscription) to hook your cartoDB account to google drive, or data in dropbox. It would at least be a start and you can build off of it [with their APIs](http://cartodb.com/develop/).